# Different file size between powershell and cmd

Tags: node.js, windows, powershell, cmd

I am using a little `processconf.js` tool to build a `configuration.json` file from multiple **.json** files.

Here the command I am using :

```
node processconf.js file1.json file2.json > configuration.json
```

I was using `cmd` for a moment, but today I tried using `Powershell` and somehow from the **same files** and the **same command** I do have different results.

One file is **33kb**(cmd) the other **66kb**(powershell), looking at the files they have the exact same lines and I can't find any visual differences, why is that ?

Comment: Sounds like they have different encodings. Also .. why is that an issue?

Comment: I thought so, I just wanted to understand why, and how could I get the same result as cmd using powershell ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PowerShell defaults to UTF16LE, while `cmd` doesn't do Unicode by default for redirection (which *may* sometimes end up mangling your data as well).

If you don't use the redirection operator in PowerShell but instead `Out-File` you can specify an encoding, e.g.

```
node processconf.js file1.json file2.json | Out-File -Encoding Utf8 configuration.json
```

I think `-Encoding Oem` would be somewhat the same as the `cmd` behaviour, but usually doesn't support Unicode and there's a conversion involved.

The redirection operator of course has no provisions for specifying any options, so it's often not the best choice when you care about the exact output format. And since PowerShell, contrary to Unix shells, handles objects, text and random binary data are very different things.

You'd get the same behaviour from `cmd` if you ran it with `cmd /u`, by the way.

Comment: It's worth noting that `Out-File -Encoding Utf8` will write an UTF-8 BOM to the file, and that other consumers of the file might choke on that. This is especially relevant to JSON files as they are more likely to be transferred to other computers.

Comment: Good answer, but it's `-Encoding OEM` that's the equivalent of `cmd.exe`'s default behavior. In PSv5.1+ you can change the default encoding for `>` with something like `$PSDefaultParameterValues['Out-File:Encoding'] = 'utf8'`

Comment: The optimum would be an UTF-8 encoded file without BOM, but that's not straight-forward to produce in PowerShell code. It involves using a BOM-free encoding instance (`$Utf8NoBOM = New-Object System.Text.UTF8Encoding $False`) and writing the file not with `Out-File` but with `[System.IO.File]::WriteAllText($path, $text, $Utf8NoBOM)`.

Comment: @Tomalak: Yeah, that's a solution that I usually use. When using PowerShell as some sort of `sed` or other processing tool for text files it's remarkably cumbersome because I tend to go through `[File]::ReadAllText` and `[File]::WriteAllText` (or even treat the file just as Latin1 and read as one single string) to avoid changing too much (not nice for diffs in source control and subsequent merges).

Comment: @Tomalak WriteAllText will write the file into one single line right, I may lose \n \t characters right ?

Comment: @LoganWlv No, `WriteAllText` will write the string *exactly* as you pass it.